# Edit the levels of several columns at once in R

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

I am trying to set the levels of several factor columns to the following values "No" and "Yes".
I use the following code but it does not work

```
binaryCol <- c(5:10, 15:19, 21:26, 30:32) # position of the columns for which I want to change the factors
for( i in binaryCol) {levels(df[,i])<- c("No","Yes")}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Now that I look at it, your code works just fine. What "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine with a simple example:

```
binaryCol <- c(1,3)
df <- data.frame(Var1=factor(1:0), Var2=1:2, Var3=factor(0:1))
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    1    1    0
#2    0    2    1

for(i in binaryCol) { levels(df[,i]) <- c("No","Yes") }
df
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1  Yes    1   No
#2   No    2  Yes
```

Alternatively, use `lapply` to apply a function to your selected `factor` columns:

```
df[binaryCol] <- lapply(df[binaryCol], function(x) {levels(x) <- c("No","Yes"); x })

df
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1  Yes    1   No
#2   No    2  Yes
```

Or if you want to be tricky:

```
df[binaryCol] <- lapply(df[binaryCol], `levels<-`, c("No","Yes") )
```

Comment: Strangely enough my original code does NOT change the original levels and after running it, if I run a str(df), I still have 0 and 1 as levels.

But the following code that you provided does the job perfectly so thank you!
    df[binaryCol] <- lapply(df[binaryCol], function(x) {levels(x) <-c("No","Yes"); x })